# "A garage is the most useful present I have ever received." and others variations (grammar and word order)

Tags: word-order

I have a little confusion. Which below sentences are correct? Could you explain my mistakes if they are?

As I understand, common word order are in the 1 & 2 sentences. But may be also possible word order is as it's written in the 3 & 4 sentences.

Please explain which verb is more appropriate here: "is" or "was".

> 1) A garage **is** the most useful present I have ever received.
>
> 2) A garage **was** the most useful present I have ever received.
>
> 3) The most useful present I have ever received **is** a garage.
>
> 4) The most useful present I have ever received **was** a garage.

TIA

Comment: Both the first two are "credible" and effectively they mean the same. Personally I'd be far more inclined to discard Present Perfect ***have*** from the second one, but that's just a stylistic choice (I *might* also do that for the first version, it's just less likely). The second pair are just "same but different". The small shift in word sequence (reversing the two nouns) has no syntactic implications for anything else in such **A is B / B is A** "copula" contexts.

Comment: All of the variations are fine. My only hesitation (which has nothing to do with the syntax) is the fact that a garage is a strange thing to receive as a present, although certainly not impossible. I suppose somebody could pay the cost of having a garage built. But if you wanted to discuss the difference between **is** and **was**, I would have picked something else a little more normal to receive as a present.

Comment: In our country a garage often is a separate building in the cooperative. Instead of a garage you can use another word if you want. It doesn't matter.